# if SSL v3 disabled on www.google.com, why does openssl output suggest SSL v3 is being used?

Tags: tls

Auditing tools like
https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/?url=www.google.com
report that SSL v3 is disabled on www.google.com (as you'd expect; with the security flaws that have been discovered in SSL v3, a company like Google isn't going to forget to turn it off).

But then, how come when I connect to it with openssl and grep the output for "ssl":

```
openssl s_client -state -connect www.google.com:443 | grep -i "ssl"
```

the output references SSLv3 multiple times?

```
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
depth=1 /C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
SSL handshake has read 2450 bytes and written 447 bytes
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
SSL-Session:
```

I do see the reference to "TLSv1/SSLv3".  I've heard that "TLS uses SSL certificates" although I don't understand the details, but does that mean that this connection is using the TLS *protocol* but using SSLv3 *certificates*, and that's why I see all the references to SSLv3 even though we're not using the SSLv3 protocol?

(I assume this is more of a conceptual question than a programming question which is why I'm posting it here instead of Stack Overflow.)

Comment: If you look at the indented lines _after_ `SSL -Session:` which you did not post, the line for `Protocol:` tells the protocol version that was negotiated. You can also specify the exact version to negotiate with `-ssl3` or `-tls1` (or `-tls1_1` or `-tls1_2` in OpenSSL 1.0.1 up) and see them fail and succeed respectively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These messages are coming from [`SSL_state_string_long`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2o/ssl/ssl_stat.c#L88), and many of them were updated in [version 1.1.0](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0/ssl/ssl_stat.c#L40) from "SSLv3 [message]" to "SSLv3/TLS [message]", so my guess would be that OpenSSL uses the same code for SSL 3 and TLS handshakes, and you're just using a version before 1.1.0 where the messages weren't yet updated to account for that.

You can see [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2o/ssl/ssl_locl.h#L866) and [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2o/ssl/t1_clnt.c#L78) for 1.0.2 that TLS uses many ssl3 functions, only swapping out those that are incompatible. This has been moved in 1.1.0 so that all of the implementations are in [methods.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0h/ssl/methods.c).

Comment: Oh OK yes mine is ancient, OpenSSL 0.9.8e.

Comment: Relatedly note the _function_ names in the code, which appear in the errorstack display, are `ssl3_` for some functions also used by TLS, and `tls1_` for some functions shared with 1.1 and 1.2 (and 1.3, in OpenSSL 1.1.1 only)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I noticed that when I was debugging but forgot to include it in my answer, thanks for the reminder!